# MongoDB replicat set secondary node changed to primary unreasonable

Tags: mongodb, cluster-computing

my mongodb rs configure resemble:

```
node1:shard1 primary,shard2 primary 
node2:shard1 secondary,shard2 secondary 
node3:shard1 arbiter,shard2 artbite
```

every time there are many writes and read,but yesterday I found the mode1 become secondary,contrast,node2 become primary,I'm very weird,so post this issue,hoping more opnions.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A primary stepping down to become a secondary is not unusual in a Replica Set, and will happen for one of three reasons.

1. It is told to by the [`replSetStepDown`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/replSetStepDown/#replSetStepDown) command
2. The primary cannot contact a majority of nodes
3. It sees that a secondary is more eligible to be primary and has a higher priority.

A secondary can also call for an election if it cannot contact a primary, or if the primary is too slow to respond.  The election will force the primary to step down.

You can read more about this process in the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication-internals/#replica-set-election-internals)

Comment: ,Thank you very much,now I have another question please kindly help me.
you know my cluster orgnization,now I wanna upgade artiter to secondary in order to reduce the pressure of the old secondary(read pressure).
then I add new member and then remove the arbiter,when I checked the rs.status() everything goes well.but the question is that the read requests still hit on the old secondary rather the both secondaris when I used mongostat --discover check,the new secondary no query.so my purpose not achived.I used java client and used slaveOk() method.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The `SlaveOK` setting will try and pick the closest Secondary by ping.  Do your app servers connect to the same `mongos`?    You might also want to test with `SlaveOk` off and see if reading from the secondary is actually gaining you that much performance.  There have also been many improvements in locking and yielding made since 1.8.2, you might want to consider upgrading.

Comment: yes,connect to the same mongoS.
When I set slaveOk off,I found all of the reads to primary,so in this situation primary pressure very huge.
I try to use tag set to indicate the read perferences,but I haven't understand how to use it.
Any advice?
Thank you very much

Comment: If you have many `mongos` processes you should have your app servers connect to more than the single `mongos` you seem to be connecting to now.  We normally suggest having a `mongos` on each app server and having the app server connect to that process.  Tag sets are a new feature in 2.2, they aren't available in the version you are using (1.8.2).  You can see the [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Tag+Aware+Sharding) for more information

Comment: Dear Andre,allow me ask a silly question:how to connect more than one mongoS,use code resemble following?
List addrs = new ArrayList();

addrs.add( new ServerAddress( nodeS1, 3000 ) );

addrs.add( new ServerAddress( nodeS2, 3000 ) );

addrs.add( new ServerAddress( nodes3, 27019 ) );

Mongo mongo = new Mongo( addrs );

and now my mongoS processes resident the same machin with mongod,should I move the mongoS process to the machin of app server?
and why?for better performance?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Ordinarily you would have many app servers each with a `mongos` process on them, then the App Server would connect it's own `mongos`.  You don't want to connect to more than one {{mongos}}.

Comment: But I'm considering if assign mongoS with mongod on the same machine more better for the performance,rather than assign mongoS with appServer on same machine.(Base on network conditions)
And In the other hand assign mongoS with mongod, then, the mongoS would connect this mongod(in the same machine,as you said nearest one) so implement my purpose participate the read pressure.If assign mongoS with appserver I'm afraid that all of the mongoS connect to one same secondary.Does it make sense?
Disturb you again,Thank you very much.

Comment: The job of the `mongos` is to connect to many `mongod` in order to route queries to the correct location, and to aggregate results from shards.  You also should be aware that the `mongos` will use some resources, which leaves less for `mongod` if they are on the same machine.  Those are two reasons you should keep the `mongos` and `mongod` processes separate.